Remove red frame around unicode chars with minted
With this example, the wave symbol has a red frame around it:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}

\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("fontfallback",
    {
      "DroidSansFallback:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}[
  Scale=0.8,
  RawFeature={fallback=fontfallback}
]

\begin{document}

\mintinline{python}{print("〜") 〜}

\end{document}


My first attempt was to redefine the style in Pygments:
from pygments.styles import get_style_by_name
from pygments.token import Token

class YcrStyle(get_style_by_name('trac')):
    styles = get_style_by_name('trac').styles
    styles.update({
        Token.Other: 'border: #ffffff',
        Token.Error: 'border: #ffffff',
    })

But I realized this is not a portable solution. The style has to be put in the pygments/styles directory not located in my project. So I tried to generate the .sty version with:
formatter = LatexFormatter(style=YcrStyle)
with open('ycr.sty', 'w') as f:
    f.write(formatter.get_style_defs())

Unfortunately doing \usepackage{ycr} does not change the style. Somehow pygments overrides those definitions.
Somehow I think I need to redefine the error behavior:
\@namedef{PY@tok@err}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}

I also tried to hack the \fcolorbox with:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{mintinline}{%
  \renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

Is there a simple way of removing the red border on unknown symbols?

Quick hack: temporarily redefine \fcolorbox to just insert the text

I tried this, but still no results (I updated the question with what I tried)

Try \mintinline[ignorelexererrors]{python}{print("〜") 〜}.
